# AWS API Gateway template mapping for Kinesis stream

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-kinesis

As per aws tutorial the kinesis stream **PutRecord** expects base64encoded JSON string as data.
In my case I need to create an object inside the template mapping for integration request before it gets to the kinesis stream.

Code example from API gateway template mapper:

```
#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
#set($data = {
  "session": "$inputRoot.session",
  "customer": "$inputRoot.customer",
  "ip": "$context.identity.sourceIp"
})
{
    "StreamName": "metrics-stream",
    "Data": "$util.base64Encode($data)",
    "PartitionKey": "$input.path('$.session')",
}
```

**The problem**: Above code doesn't work since `$data` is not valid JSON string. How one can convert the `$data` to valid JSON string? Could't find a `$util` to do that inside template mapper.

Thanks!